# Excel shortcut to set font size and bold

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel budget spreadsheet that as items (cells with  numbers) are paid, I make the font bold and size 14.

Is there a way to create a shortcut to do this with one keyboard move instead of right-clicking, choosing font size 14 and then clicking on bold?

I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: You can create a macro to set your desired formatting and assign a hotkey to it.I don't think it's possible without VBA. ( hotkeys without VBA: CTRL+B for books and ALT+H+FS+14+ENTER to set font size to 14)

Answer (score 1):

Highlight necessary cells and use **Ctrl+B** to make the text bold. 
As for changing the font size use the **Home > Font tab**. Or you could use **Ctrl+Shift+P** to bring up the **format cells > font box**. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: CTL-SHF-P is the answer i was looking for thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a **Format Painter**.

[image]

Select the cell with the desired formatting and click on the Format Painter icon in your toolbar. Than click on the cell that you want to apply the formatting to.

Or as Máté Juhász suggested, you can create you own macro.
One drawback is that this macro is going to be available only in the Excel spreadsheet where the macro is set up (obviously).

Here's a macro sample:

```
    Sub Bold14PtMacro()
    '
    ' Bold14PtMacro Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
    '
        With Selection.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 14
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        End With
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
    End Sub
```